# climate and behaviour of a gaseous ocean

Tags: science-based, weather

Following up on my last question about the ecology of my skyworld [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/119935/what-would-the-ecological-effects-of-a-worldwide-ocean-of-fog-be), I decided to go more in-depth and fundamental. This is going to mostly be about the behavior of the ocean and changes to the climate of the world after the ocean is introduced. Assume that the ocean is dense enough to mostly remain pooled and the tendency of gas to mix and diffuse is handwaved. My world pre-drowning would be fairly similar to Earth and have similar atmospheric circulation, average temperature, etc as Earth.[image: this] This image from calculatedearth of the Earth's landmasses submerged to 1000 meters would be close to how my world looks. A few questions:

1. Would the ocean change the average temperature of the planet?
2. Would there be tides in the gas ocean and would they differ in nature?
3. Would the climate of surviving land be altered significantly? If so, How?
4. Would there be any new kinds of weather created by the event?

Edit:

Albedo (black mist ocean for thematic purposes): 0.1

Albedo (alternately, a "cloud sea"): 0.75

Specific heat: 5 joule/gram °C

Edit 2: For the purposes of this question, I suppose it would be better to consider simple ground fog (the kind we have on Earth) as the gas (or aerosol, actually) that covers the land. It would probably be easier to predict the effects knowing more about the substance. My only concern is that fog doesn't seem to displace air, and the depths being anaerobic is an idea I had been considering. If the aerosol particles are suspended in a denser gas/mixture than air, would that displace the atmosphere?

Comment: Do the actual (water) oceans still exist below the fog, and do they experience the time dilation effect mentioned in your other question?  Does the fog carry heat in a way similar to natural gasses and liquids (via convection)?

Comment: @realityChemist the oceans and other bodies of water still exist and they experience the time dilation. The fog does transfer heat like a normal gas. I'll add some information in the OP.

Comment: two comments: 1) I cant see the image, 2) Does the gas contain oxygen in a way that a life form could eventually adapt to live there?

Comment: I actually have a [question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/88388/is-there-dense-non-flammable-gas-that-i-can-cover-the-earth-in) on a similar scenario, asking about what kind of gas would be suitable for the ocean - hopefully you'll find the answers useful.

Answer (score 2):

1. As average temperature is a function of radiation absorption, we don't know enough about the fog to give a calculated answer to this question.
2. There probably would be tides, I wouldn't want to live near the [intertidal zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intertidal_zone) of this place at all, one [king tide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_tide) or worse a [storm surge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Storm_surge) and you could age to death in your sleep without ever knowing it.
3. That will massively depend on physical properties of the fog that are not mentioned here or in the preceding question, including but not limited to, it's permeability to solar radiation, the miscibility of water vapour, it's permeability to mobile water vapour, etc...
4. See points 1 and 3.

Given the time differential it could be argued that everything under the fog simply freezes solid within a few hours.

Comment: I added some physical info to the OP. Water vapour should be able to pass through the fog, or else the water cycle is basically dead. What I'm afraid of though is the fact that the probable cold at the bottom of the fog will prevent water from evaporating.

Comment: @user199429 Albedo doesn't help, to answer any questions about the effect on temperature and weather radiation absorption and permeability, and thus the amount of energy the surface, particularly of the oceans but also the land, under the fog gets.

Comment: What if we assume this fog really is water fog? It's an aerosol with known properties, so there is probably enough information out there. The only major difference between the aerosol I want and water fog is density, which should be able to vary without necessarily affecting the other values too much.

Comment: @user199429 That's not really an aerosol anymore, at that density it's more like a super heavy [aerogel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel). If you have water vapour at that density it's rain not fog and it would entirely opaque at a few hundred metres or less thickness.